# using local.xml to avoid repetition

Tags: layout

I hope you don't mind me expanding on [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6324/calling-css-using-layout-xml?noredirect=1#comment8742_6324) question. Using what's explained I got the css working in my template file. But I have not been able to get it working from local.xml, so I am repeating myself several times within the same layout file.

I got to thinking that a local.xml file would be useful in this situation, so what I tried to do was take the node that worked in the layout file and wrap it in a reference node in local.xml and call that reference node

This works

frontend/base/default/layout/modulename/layoutFileForModule

```
<user_register_form>
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" output="toHtml">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/normalize.css</stylesheet></action>
    </block>
    <block type="core/template" name="prefcentre_regform" output="toHtml" template="ps/prefcentre/signup.phtml" />
</user_register_form>
```

This does not work

frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

```
<reference name="someReferenceHandle">
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" output="toHtml">
        <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/normalize.css</stylesheet></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

frontend/base/default/layout/modulename/layoutFileForModule

```
<user_register_form>
    <reference name="someReferenceHandle">
        <block type="core/template" name="prefcentre_regform" output="toHtml" template="ps/prefcentre/signup.phtml" />
    </reference>
</user_register_form>
```

I have misunderstood a tutorial somewhere, I thought Magento would look for the layout.xml file first when it compiles all the .xml files, then by me using the reference handle I was able to reference the block within that handle.

Why does example one work and example two fail?

Comment: what value do you have for `someReferenceHandle`? This should be one of the existing block aliases: `root`, `head`, `footer`, `content`, `left`, `right` and so on. If you are referencing a block that does not exist, it's normal not to work.

Comment: I've been using head

Comment: then it should work. You should see the contents of the file `ps/prefcentre/signup.phtml` inside the `<head>` tag of your page....unless you were hoping to see it in the page. Then you need to modify the reference name to `header`

Comment: You should *not* be making more than one block an output block i.e. `output="toHtml"`. If you are using a standard Magento layout configuration then the root block is already an output block (ref *`page.xml`*).

Comment: would the file path change as local.xml is in frontend/base/default/layout/ and layoutFileForModule.xml is in frontend/base/default/layout/modulename/, I assume it should not matter, but as a test I added the action method=addCss node to page.xml and the css was not added

Comment: That's what I would suggest. Unlike the config xml files which seem to load xml files indiscriminately, I've always needed the path/name of layout xml files to be discretely referenced in the config.xml of a module in order to run properly. Since, I'm not seeing a file named local.xml in my layout folders, that file might not be referenced anywhere.  So, you'll probably want to move these layout updates into your module's layout xml or copy a related layout file into the theme you're using and make the changes there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you seem to have misunderstood the syntax involved in what you want to do (though it seems you've understood the principles, and that's half the battle!).

1. Don't use an `output` block with a typical Magento layout, as the **root** block is already set as an (the) output block (ref. *`page.xml`*):

   ```
   <block type="page/html_head" name="head" output="toHtml"> <!-- NO output -->
   ```
2. You should *not* be redeclaring the **head** block; rather, you should reference the one already created (again, ref *`page.xml`*):

   ```
   <!-- <block type="page/html_head" name="head" output="toHtml"> This replaces the original! -->
   <reference name="head">
       <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/normalize.css</stylesheet></action>
   </reference>
   ```
3. Collect would-be-repeated directives in a custom layout update handle and use the `<update>` directive to include them in other handles:

   ```
   <UTILITY_HANDLE>
       <reference name="head">
           <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/normalize.css</stylesheet></action>
       </reference>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="core/template" name="prefcentre_regform" template="ps/prefcentre/signup.phtml" />
       </reference>
   </UTILITY_HANDLE>
   <!-- include the above on catalog product view page -->
   <catalog_product_view>
       <update handle="UTILITY_HANDLE" />
   </catalog_product_view>
   ```